# Could we make a form in dynamics CRM that will be based on an another?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

I wonder is it possible to create a form which will based on an another.

for example, I'm creating a new account and, initially, I know that I have to create about 10 accounts yet. The point is that, all of them have pretty the same data (address, country, cellphone number...)

So, I think it will much better if I had a feature that allow me to create another account by opening the same form and just edit/add data that is distinct.

Have anyone faced that issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the next two options for do that, take a look:

- [Without code](http://rc.crm.dynamics.com/RC/2011/en-us/online/5.1_CTP/cloneRecords.aspx) - Work with self-referencing relationship and manage the mappings.
- [Javascript Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602956.aspx#BKMK_OpenEntityForm) - This way is a new way to open a entity form, and if we pass null to id created a new record of that entity, and you can pass default values. Only works at least in rollup 8.

Comment: thanks a lot, you've made me happy today)) the first one work great!)

Comment: Pedro it's normally good practice to summarise the pertinent parts of the links you have referenced - that way if the link ever breaks then your StackOverflow answer can still be useful :)

Comment: Ok Greg in my next questions i will take that in consideration. Thanks for the advices. I modify my post. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You could add a button on the Account form ribbon called "New Account".
The button could call a JavaScript function that pops a new Account and populates it with every value from the current record.
Alternatively you could add a lookup to another Account called "Account Template".
Code is waiting on-change of the lookup and populates the form with all the attribute values from the "Account Template" Account.

Comment: thx, good points. Could you tell me about the second one a little bit more? I'm a bit confused what the "lookup" is and how to create it?

Comment: The lookup is a field on the Account form that references another Account; it is sort of like the Parent Account field, but it would be providing default values for the Account. You add the lookup field to the Account entity and then to the Account form; you are either going to have to use Xrm.Page in JavaScript, a workflow, or a plug-in. A workflow process is the only non-code way to dynamically populate fields. I suggest you check out some tutorials on adding fields and creating workflows in Microsoft Dynamics CRM.

Comment: I think I got what you're talking about. You mean, due to lookup field I could find something account and take data from its form, right?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking to clone the entities of an existing record so that you can create a new record with least efforts of entering the same data. If that is your problem, you have a readymade solution available... check Record Clone add for Dynamics CRM here... You can also try it for free of cost : https://www.iotap.com/ProductDetail/tabid/788/ProductID/28/RecordClone-CRM2011-FREETRIAL/Default.aspx

Regards,
Jahnavi
jray@iotap.com

Comment: actually, it cost pretty many, man) Price: $249.00 for that Addon. I've already solved it, thx